# NSKeyedArchiver works with simulator but not actual device

Tags: ios, objective-c

So I implemented these two functions to save data in my app:

```
- (NSString*)itemArchivePath
{
   NSArray* documentDirectories = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
   NSString* documentDirectory = [documentDirectories firstObject];

   return [documentDirectory stringByAppendingString:@"items.archive"];
}


-(BOOL)saveChanges
{
   NSString* path = [self itemArchivePath];
   return [NSKeyedArchiver archiveRootObject:self.highScores toFile:path];
}
```

It saves everything perfectly on the iOS simulator, but when I run it on an actual iPhone, it doesn't save anything. Most of the app is written in swift, but I wouldn't think that that is the problem. And also I did implement the protocol for `NSCoding`.

Answer (score 2):

You are building your path incorrectly.

This:

```
return [documentDirectory stringByAppendingString:@"items.archive"];
```

needs to be:

```
return [documentDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"items.archive"];
```

Your original code results in a path like:

> some path to app/Documentsitems.archive

Notice the lack of a slash before the filename.